# How to view resource permissions with SelfSubjectRulesReview using curl

Tags: rest, curl, post, kubernetes, api-design

In Kubernetes you can use the `auth can-i` command to check if you have permissions to some resource.
For example, I can use this command like that on the worker:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf auth can-i get pods -v 9
```

It will check if you have permissions to view pods, and when you add the `-v` flag it show the verbose output:

```
...
curl -k -v -XPOST  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.18.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/9e99141" 'https://<master_ip>:6443/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1/selfsubjectaccessreviews'
```

I wanted to use this REST API with `curl` and it doesn't work:

```
curl --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt \
     --cert /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem \
     --key /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem \
     -d @- \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Accept: application/json, */*" \
     -XPOST https://<master_ip>:6443/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1/selfsubjectrulesreviews <<'EOF'
{
   "kind":"SelfSubjectAccessReview",
   "apiVersion":"authorization.k8s.io/v1",
   "metadata":{
      "creationTimestamp":null
   },
   "spec":{
      "namespace":"default"
   },
   "status":{
      "allowed":true
   }
}
EOF
```

If failed with the error:

```
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "SelfSubjectAccessReview in version \"v1\" cannot be handled as a SelfSubjectRulesReview: converting (v1.SelfSubjectAccessReview).v1.SelfSubjectAccessReviewSpec to (authorization.SelfSubjectRulesReview).authorization.SelfSubjectRulesReviewSpec: Namespace not present in src",
  "reason": "BadRequest",
  "code": 400
```

How can I use SelfSubjectRulesReview API with curl to view resource permissions?

---

Thanks to @HelloWorld I found the problem, the issue was with the different between selfsubjectaccessreviews vs selfsubjectrulesreviews. I will put 2 working `curl` examples.

1) **selfsubjectaccessreviews** example to see if the account has permissions for

```
curl --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt \
     --cert /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem \
     --key /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem \
     -d @- \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H 'Accept: application/json, */*' \
     -XPOST https://<master_ip>:6443/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1/selfsubjectaccessreviews <<'EOF'
{
   "kind":"SelfSubjectAccessReview",
   "apiVersion":"authorization.k8s.io/v1",
   "metadata":{
      "creationTimestamp":null
   },
   "spec":{
      "resourceAttributes":{
         "namespace":"default",
         "verb":"get",
         "resource":"pods"
      }
   },
   "status":{
   }
}
EOF
```

2) **selfsubjectrulesreviews** example to see all the permissions of the account on the default namespace:

```
curl --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt \
     --cert /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem \
     --key /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem \
     -d @- \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H 'Accept: application/json, */*' \
     -XPOST https://<master_ip>:6443/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1/selfsubjectrulesreviews <<'EOF'
{
   "kind":"SelfSubjectRulesReview",
   "apiVersion":"authorization.k8s.io/v1",
   "metadata":{
      "creationTimestamp":null
   },
   "spec":{
     "namespace":"default"
   },
   "status":{
   }
}
EOF
```

Comment: What k8s version are you using?

Comment: Kubernetes v1.18.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that kubectl verbose shows this url in output:

```
https://<master_ip>:6443/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1/selfsubjectaccessreviews
```

and you are curling:

```
https://<master_ip>:6443/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1/selfsubjectrulesreviews
```

Can you notice the difference? selfsubject**accessreviews** vs selfsubject**rulesreviews**.

Change the url to correct one and it will work.

Comment: Great, nice catch :) Although after I change to `selfsubjectaccessreviews` it worked, I still needed `selfsubjectrulesreviews` to see all the permissions but because of your answer I found the problem and now I now how to view both of them. I will update my answer with the correct command, thanks !